# .NET Core MVC - Binding DateTime always Results in MinValue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a `BirthDate`property in my model looking like this

```
[Required]
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = @"{0:MM/dd/yyy}")]
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
```

In my view, I'm binding this property to an `input` using `asp-for` tag helper. It looks like this:

```
<input class="form-control" type="date" name="dateofbirth" id="inputDateOfBirth" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" data-date-format="mm/dd/yyyy"
               max="@DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")" asp-for="FamilyMember.BirthDate" required/>
```

When posting the form to the controller, the `BirthDate` property is always set to `01/01/0001`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your html element is using the `asp-for` tag helper, but you're also specifying `name="dateofbirth"` and `id="inputDateOfBith"`. Removing that will post the correct value.

`Asp-for`, when rendered, will populate an `input` element with the specified model-bound property `id` and `name` already (among other things like value, validation, etc.). You can read about this and more on Microsoft's official [ASP.NET Core tag helper documentation.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-3.1#the-input-tag-helper)

Straight from their documentation:

> Generates the id and name HTML attributes for the expression name specified in the asp-for attribute. asp-for="Property1.Property2" is equivalent to m => m.Property1.Property2. The name of the expression is what is used for the asp-for attribute value. See the Expression names section for additional information.

Comment: Good call. Once I saw the `name` attribute, it all clicked.